# need sql for room availability in a hotel booking system

Tags: php, mysql

Here my mysql database:

```
tbl_room

room_id || room_name || room_qty

tbl_reservation

reservation_id || check_in_date || check_out_date || room_id || reserved_qty
```

I need a sql query for summation of specific room reserved quantity in respect of customer given date(start and end).

I have tried below this.

```
SELECT sum( reserved_qty )
FROM `tbl_reservation`
WHERE ( 13/09/2014
BETWEEN check_in_date
AND check_out_date )
OR (
check_out_date
BETWEEN 11/09/2014
AND 13/09/2014
)
OR (
check_in_date
BETWEEN 11/09/2014
AND 13/09/2014
)
OR ( 11/09/2014
BETWEEN check_in_date
AND check_out_date )
AND room_id=1
```

But this is not working.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to lack research.

Comment: Note that dates in MySQL adhere to a specific format.

Comment: a) Stack Overflow isn’t a website to get professional developers to write code for you, and b) research the problem and try and solve it yourself first. You seem to have a poor knowledge of MySQL (using not-standard date formats) so I suggest you read the basis on the SQL query language first.

Answer (score 0):

You tried find sum for field "no_of_room". But I can't see this field in tables. Maybe you need use other aggregate function here? Like sum(reserved_qty)?

Comment: sorry for that, it's my writing mistake on stackoverflow.